# Where is CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO in make menuconfig?

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration, compiling, gentoo

I'm trying to compile a Linux Kernel to run light and paravirtualized on XenServer 5.6 fp1.

I'm using the guide given here: http://www.mad-hacking.net/documentation/linux/deployment/xen/pv-guest-basics.xml

But I'm stumped when I reached the option `CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO`.

Where is it exactly in `make menuconfig`? The site indicated that the options is in the *Processor type and features* group, but I don't see it:

```
[*] Tickless System (Dynamic Ticks)                                  
[*] High Resolution Timer Support                                    
[*] Symmetric multi-processing support                               
[ ] Support for extended (non-PC) x86 platforms                      
[ ] Single-depth WCHAN output                                        
[*] Paravirtualized guest support  --->                              
[*] Disable Bootmem code (NEW)                                       
[ ] Memtest (NEW)                                                    
    Processor family (Core 2/newer Xeon)  --->                       
(2) Maximum number of CPUs                                           
[ ] SMT (Hyperthreading) scheduler support                           
[ ] Multi-core scheduler support                                     
    Preemption Model (No Forced Preemption (Server))  --->           
[ ] Reroute for broken boot IRQs                                     
[ ] Machine Check / overheating reporting                            
< > Dell laptop support (NEW)                                        
< > /dev/cpu/microcode - microcode support                           
<M> /dev/cpu/*/msr - Model-specific register support                 
<M> /dev/cpu/*/cpuid - CPU information support                       
[ ] Numa Memory Allocation and Scheduler Support                     
    Memory model (Sparse Memory)  --->                               
[*] Sparse Memory virtual memmap (NEW)                               
[*] Allow for memory hot-add                                         
[*]   Allow for memory hot remove                                    
[ ] Allow for memory compaction                                      
[*] Page migration                                                   
[*] Enable KSM for page merging                                      
(65536) Low address space to protect from user allocation (NEW)      
[ ] Check for low memory corruption                                  
[ ] Reserve low 64K of RAM on AMI/Phoenix BIOSen                     
-*- MTRR (Memory Type Range Register) support                        
[ ]   MTRR cleanup support                                           
[*] Enable seccomp to safely compute untrusted bytecode (NEW)        
[*] Enable -fstack-protector buffer overflow detection (EXPERIMENTAL)
    Timer frequency (100 HZ)  --->                                   
[ ] kexec system call                                                
[ ] kernel crash dumps                                               
[*] Build a relocatable kernel (NEW)                                 
-*- Support for hot-pluggable CPUs                                   
[ ] Built-in kernel command line (NEW)
```

FYI, I'm configuring **Gentoo's Kernel v2.6.36-hardened-r9**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you had already said, it IS under "Processor Types and Features".

You are compiling Gentoo's hardened kernel source, so the code would have undergone many patches.

A quick search in Google returned this: [Gentoo kernel VDSO](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/linux-patches/hardened/2.6/tags/2.6.28-6/4445_disable-compat_vdso.patch?revision=1528&view=markup). It looks like Gentoo has it disabled even several versions before.

Why don't you download directly from kernel.org?

Comment: Specifically, it's between "Support for hot-pluggable CPUs" and "Built-in kernel command line" on a non-hardened source (2.6.36-gentoo-r5)

Comment: d'oh~ >.< ... I knew I was having a stupid moment there when the answer is staring at me right in my eye (i.e., "hardened"). as to your question, I prefer using the Gentoo-blessed kernels ;)

Comment: @Michael thanks. I should've first checked what options "hardened" left out. /me = having st00pid n00b moments